# Exponential distribution.Bank waiting time

Tags: probability-distributions

I am at a total loss with that problem:
Consider a bank with three tellers and a single waiting line.Every customer of the bank is serviced,when he reaches the top of the waiting queue,by one and only teller(whichever is available).Suppose that the service time for all the tellers is exponentially distributed with mean 30 min.
At one time there are 6 customers at the bank.A,B and C occupying the tellers and X,Y,Z waiting in line(at that order).

a)What is the probability of A leaving the bank first?
b)What is the probability of A leaving the bank before B does?
c)what is the probability of Z leaving before X?
d)what is the average waiting time of Z at the waiting line?
e)what is the average time that Z remains at the bank(waiting and being serviced)?

EDIT:So the question was put on hold.I'm guessing because I didn't provide any work I did.The thing is everything I did seems to lead nowhere so it seemed pointless to post it.What I did so far step by step.Calculated λ=1/30 for each teller.I found that the expected waiting time for client D is 10.10 minutes.For (a) I tried doing something like P(x

Comment: Nice problem. If really you can solve no piece of it, the situation is... well, problematic.

Comment: So far I could manage anything thrown at me,but this has me at a corner.This is the first time I posted at a forum.Talk about problematic xD

Comment: The trouble is that, if (a) eludes you, the rest is squarely out of reach.

Comment: "For (a) I tried doing something like P(x" Suspense...